# how to get the selected cell values and unselected cell values in uitableview in different array using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[pls check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEOOc.png)

i am very new to iOS how to get the selected cell values in one array and unselected cell value in the another array using by using checkmarks in objective c

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 { 
  NSArray *selectedRows=[_mytableview indexPathsForSelectedRows];
indexofselectedcell = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

valueofselectedcell = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<selectedRows.count; i++) {
   [indexofselectedcell addObject:indexPath
     customcell *cell = (customcell *)[_mytableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *test = cell.balance.text;
    [valueofselectedcell addObject:test];
    NSLog(@"%@ the value of the selected cell value is ",valueofselectedcell);
    NSArray *array = [valueofselectedcell copy];
    NSNumber* sum = [array valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];
    NSLog(@"the sum valuie is .... %@",sum);
    NSString *totalamount = [sum stringValue];
    _amountlabel.text=totalamount;
    NSInteger index = [valueofselectedcell indexOfObject:totalamount];
    NSLog(@"%ld the index value in the array is",(long)index);

}}
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *totalamount;
if ([indexofselectedcell containsObject: indexPath])
{
    NSInteger anIndex=[indexofselectedcell indexOfObject:indexPath];
    [indexofselectedcell removeObjectAtIndex:anIndex];
    [valueofselectedcell removeObjectAtIndex:anIndex];
    NSLog(@"the value of the unselected cell value is..... %@",valueofselectedcell);
    NSArray *array = [valueofselectedcell copy];
    NSNumber* sum = [array valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];
   totalamount = [sum stringValue];
    _amountlabel.text=totalamount;
    totalamount= nil;
}   }
```

Comment: add your tried code

Comment: i added the code pls check it . I am trying to get the selected values of uitableview and make it sum and display it in to the uilabel. This above code not working properly when the two cells getting selected if i try to remove the selected values only one row getting deleted .this is my problem .

Comment: try this type code in didselect
    if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [invite_friend1 addObject:json_invite_friend[indexPath.row][@"to_id"]];
        NSLog(@"ID=%@",invite_friend1);
    }
    else
    {
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [invite_friend1 removeObject:json_invite_friend[indexPath.row][@"to_id"]];
        NSLog(@"ID=%@",invite_friend1);
    }

Comment: you solved your problem

Comment: not yet sir still i am trying i just need the multiple selection in my tableview and add that selected cell values and display it in to label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavithra I tried sample project for your question and output.If I get unselected and selected cells in separate array,it crashed as I could not check two array in cellForRowAtIndexPath.So that I save selected and unSelected values in one array.

I created simple understandable solution.I have set values in tableview as unselected as default.If you selected(when you click the cell) it shows UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and other show UITableViewCellAccessoryNone.

It works perfectly.You can easily get.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController :  UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewSelectUnSelect;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *arrVal,*arrSelectedUnSelectedValues,*arrSelectedValues,*arrUnSelectedValues;
    NSMutableArray *arrSubTitle;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableViewSelectUnSelect;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    arrVal= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"India",@"China",@"Korea",@"Japan",@"Peru",@"Italy",@"France",@"US",@"Dubai",@"UK",@"Nepal",nil];
    arrSubTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"100",@"70",@"80",@"90",@"50",@"60",@"70",@"50",@"40",@"30",@"80",nil];
    arrSelectedUnSelectedValues= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrSelectedValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrUnSelectedValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int j=0;j<[arrVal count];j++)
    {
        [arrSelectedUnSelectedValues addObject:@"unselected"]; //As Default it is in UnSelected State
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrVal.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *strCell = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:strCell];
    }
    if([[arrSelectedUnSelectedValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"selected"])
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrVal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [arrSubTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    @try
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [cell convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableViewSelectUnSelect];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewSelectUnSelect indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
        NSLog(@"The arrSelectedUnSelectedValues  are %@",arrSelectedUnSelectedValues );
        NSString *strValue;

        if([arrSelectedUnSelectedValues count]==0)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<[arrVal count]; i++)
            {
                [arrSelectedUnSelectedValues addObject:@"unselected"];
            }
        }
        if([[arrSelectedUnSelectedValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"selected"])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [arrSelectedUnSelectedValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"unselected"];
            strValue = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
            [arrUnSelectedValues addObject:strValue];
            NSLog(@"The arrUnSelectedValues are - %@",arrUnSelectedValues);
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [arrSelectedUnSelectedValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"selected"];
            strValue = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
            [arrSelectedValues addObject:strValue];
            NSLog(@"The arrSelectedValues - %@",arrSelectedValues);
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"The exception is-%@",exception);
    }
}

@end
```

First when I run the application it shows like below
[image]

Then when I select values from the tableView
[image]

Then finally printed results are
[image]

Comment: hi i tried your sample but it showing the error inside that for loop like ''NO visible @interface for NSMutableArray'' declares the selector ':' "how to solve this error

Comment: i solved that issue it is working fine but i need the selected cell values in array so that only i can sum the selected cell values and display it in to the label. can u please suggest me how i can do this

Comment: Then do one thing.Create another mutable array. If it is selected , save that value into new array.Also if is unselected, save that in another mutable array.You need to do this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @pavithra just add and remove selected value in array

Comment: Where do you use the label in your ViewController?

Comment: Reply me according to my above comments.Quickly

Comment: sorry for my late reply sir i just tried your sample code but i didn't get the arrSubTitle array in the tableview at last i have to display the label and have to show the sum value

Comment: i added the image also pls check it sir

Comment: Please use my answer fully.I updated it.You used my old code.

Comment: See my above code in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I set         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:strCell] and cell.detailTextLabel.text = [arrSubTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Did you get the solution?